# Javascript calculate same weekday next year

Tags: javascript, date, leap-year

I have some trouble to calculate the weekday of a given date next year. For example: Tuesday, 19. April 2016 is the given date. Now I would calculate: TUESDAY, 18. April 2017. It is very important that the weekdays are always the same.

My problem are the leap-years. I hope you could help me.

```
$('.changeYear').click(function() {
        var appointments = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 22; i++) {
            var date = $('#tr-fix-tag-' + i).val();
            if (date !== "") {
                var splittedDate = date.substr(5).split('.');
                appointments.push(new Date(splittedDate[2], splittedDate[1] - 1, splittedDate[0]));
            }
        }

        var counter = 1;
        $.each(appointments, function() {
            var field = $('#tr-fix-tag-' + counter);
            var date = $(this)[0];
            var newDate = new Date(date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1));

            if (isSchaltjahr(newDate.getFullYear()))
                field.val(formatDate(new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 2))));
            else
                field.val(formatDate(new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 1))));

            counter++;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try to checkout doomsday algorithm. The mathematical formula should give you an idea of how to code it.http://www.timeanddate.com/date/doomsday-weekday.html

Comment: So are you looking for say the 3rd Tuesday in April each year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a year and keep the day the same, you can adjust the resulting date by however many days are required to the nearest date of the same day, e.g.

```js
function sameDayNextYear(d) {
  // Copy date
  var t = new Date(+d);
  // Get current day number
  var startDayNum = d.getDay();
  // Add one year
  t.setFullYear(t.getFullYear() + 1);
  // Move to closest day that is the same day number
  var diff = startDayNum - t.getDay();
  // If diff is more than 3 days, need to subtract rather than add
  diff = (diff > 3) ? diff-7 : diff;
  t.setDate(t.getDate() + diff);
  return t;  
}

[new Date(2016, 1, 13),  // Sat 13 Feb 2016 - Sat 11 Feb 2017
 new Date(2016, 1, 5),   // Fri 05 Feb 2016 - Fri 03 Feb 2017
 new Date(2016, 1, 6),   // Sat 06 Feb 2016 - Sat 04 Feb 2017
 new Date(2016, 1, 29),  // Mon 29 Feb 2016 - Mon 27 Feb 2017
 new Date(2016, 2, 1)]   // Tue 01 Mar 2016 - Tue 28 Feb 2017
 .forEach(function(d) {
  document.write(d + '<br>' + sameDayNextYear(d) + '<br><br>');
});
```

The above will work for any day in any year, leap or otherwise.

However, for some dates this means it will go to the next or previous month (e.g. 2016-03-01 goes to 2017-02-28). If you don't want that to happen, you can compare the start and end months and either add or subtract a week to get back to the original month (so to 2017-03-07).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this, and walk in the direction of your target day:

```
var DayOfWeek=[
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
]

function GetDayOfWeek(year, month, day)
{
    var monthAdjust = [ 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 ];
    year -= (month < 3) ? 1 : 0;
  var leap = Math.floor(year / 4);
  var greg = Math.floor(year / 100);
  var modern = Math.floor(year / 400);

    return DayOfWeek[(year + leap - greg + modern + monthAdjust[month - 1] + day) % 7];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest way that i could get it to work. This could probably be optimized a lot.

Here is a DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/92fLoryo/

Pretty much it gets the date of next year, and then it subtracts and adds 7 days to that date looking for the same weekday. And it will pick the closest to the date.

```
function getNextYearWeekday(today)
{
  var weekday = today.getDay();
    var temp = new Date();
  temp.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 1);

    var previous = 0;
  var next = 0;

  // Check Previous Days
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    temp.setDate(today.getDate() - i);
    console.log(temp);
    if (weekday == temp.getDay())
    {
        previous = i;
    }
  }

  // reset the date
  temp = new Date();
  temp.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 1);

  // Check Next Days
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    temp.setDate(today.getDate() + i);
    console.log(temp);
    if (weekday == temp.getDay())
    {
        next = i;
    }
  }

  // reset the date
  temp = new Date();
  temp.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 1);

  // find out which one is closer
  if (previous < next)
    temp.setDate(temp.getDate() - previous);
  else
    temp.setDate(temp.getDate() + next);

    return temp;
}
```